# Win32DiskImager fails to launch

Tags: windows, disk-imaging

I downloaded Win32DiskImager from SourceForge, as was recommended in some Linux installation instruction (coming from Windows).  The installer runs successfully and the program is installed into C:\Program Files (x86) as expected.  When launching the program Windows prompts me to accept that this program can make changes, I accept and nothing happens.  No service or process launches in Task Manger.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

It turns out that mounted drives can cause issues with Win32DiskImager.  In my case Google Drive had mounted itself on the file system.  Quitting Google Drive unmounted the drive it had mounted and then Win32DiskImager launched without issue!  I also had a Linux ISO mounted (I believe Windows did this automatically after download, which seems odd) and had unmounted that as well before re-launching Win32DiskImager.

Comment: This fixed it for me, too; it was Google Drive. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Google Drive was the problem

Comment: For me it was VeraCrypt container. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: damned GoogleDriver :D

Comment: Personally I had ImDisk Virtual Disk to blame. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Unfortunately the topic is closed. I had the same issue, but could not find/unmount the device. I assume it's because of bitlocker, I had the same situation with veracrypt in the past.
v1.0.0 of Win32 Disk Imager won't show up, therefore I tried v0.9.5. The older version throws two error messages, then shows up and I can flash the usb stick.

Comment: thanks you so much. this is one most strange behaviour that  see

Comment: Yep. That did it.

Comment: This is also caused by mounted VeraCrypt drives. Unmount all drives and you should be able to start Win32DiskImager.

Tobin Davis has analyzed but not fixed this bug since August 2018 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+bug/1672552). Four years ago; it seems this bug will remain.

Comment: Well, this question is definitely about a software tool and the answer saved me lot of time and frustration. Definitely an issue when backing up Raspberry images with Windows 10.

Comment: killing Google Drive worked
but why?

Comment: lol and it is working again. I thought the program was starting in the background and a h4ck3r is watching me... But it was just the google drive

Comment: Wow so annoying that Google drive is the issue. This should really be addressed because it's not obvious.

Comment: 2024 and still happens, killing Google Drive worked for me